# Storing Queryout in VARBINARY and emailing as attachment

Tags: sql, email, stored-procedures, varbinary

I am trying to write a SQL Stored procedure that will execute a query, store the results of that query in a csv file within a VARBINARY variable, then attach that csv file to an email.

Currently my procedure is using queryout to write the csv to a file on the server, then sends an email referencing that file, but due to process changes I'd like to get away from needing to save the file on the server if possible.

I am just not sure how to approach the issue.  I have never used the VARBINARY file type before, and I'm not sure how to dump my query into a csv in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,  well I was over complicating the issue and I needed to be a good little SQL developer and go back to the technet articles.  I didn't need to store the query results into a variable and use that as an attachment.  See link and example below for the resolution:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx

```
EXEC [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail] @profile_name = 'SQLMail',
     @recipients    = 'user@email.com',
     @subject       = 'Subject',
     @body          = 'See attached', 
     @query         = 'SELECT * FROM ##temp',
     @attach_query_result_as_file = 1,  
     @query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
     @query_result_separator = '    ',  
     @query_result_header = 1;
```